Which verb tense best completes this sentence according to Standard English conventions?

The Many Farms Chapter is one of the 110 chapters of the Navajo Nation (Naabeehó Bináhásdzó). The chapter, known as Dá’ák’eh Halání in the Navajo language (Diné bizaad), was the subject of a profile _____ in the Navajo Times on August 22, 2013.

A) appeared
B) has appeared
C) appears
D) appearing


My Answer: I believe the correct answer is D) appearing because it seems to work as a participle phrase modifying “profile.” In this context, “appearing” functions like a descriptor or continuation of the sentence rather than a finite verb. To me, it aligns with the style and flow of the sentence, though I want to ensure this interpretation is consistent with Standard English grammar conventions.
On the other hand, I also assume that the full sentence might read as follows:

The chapter was the subject of a profile that appeared in the Navajo Times on August 22, 2013.

Question: Is “appearing” a correct and valid choice here, and if not, why?

Certainly your possibilities are far more restricted when that/which is absent than when it is present, aren't they?

@Cam Yes, it's correct.

The “of a profile…” needs (according to English syntax) to be a prepositional phrase, which requires that “a profile…” be a noun phrase. But each of “a profile appeared…,” “a profile has appeared…,” and “a profile appears…” is the start of a clause (or sentence). Only “a profile appearing…” can be the start of a noun phrase.
So yes, the only correct choice is appearing.

Your answer is a bit confusing. Her explanation is great.

The thing I’m trying to say is that the sentence might also be written as: “The chapter was the subject of a profile that appeared in the Navajo Times on August 22, 2013.” Since “that” can be omitted when it is the object in a relative clause, the sentence can also be written as: “The chapter was the subject of a profile appeared in the Navajo Times on August 22, 2013.”

But relative clauses of that type cannot be reduced (in other words, shorn of their thats). Here the antecedent of that is profile, which is the subject of the active verb appeared. Reduction would be possible where a verb is being used in the passive, as in “a profile [that was] printed in the Navajo Times.”

Great explanation! Thanks @ Paul Tanenbaum!
